# Drawer Views not showing

Tags: android, navigation-drawer

My drawer views are not showing it was working fine before i didn't made any change in layout or `MainActivity` now when i m checking its showing nothing

My XML

```
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
android:orientation="vertical">

<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#71b6ca"
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
    app:title="DocVids" />

<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:background="#71b6ca"
    android:id="@+id/drawerLayout"
    >

<FrameLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/containerView">
 </FrameLayout>



<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:layout_marginTop="-24dp"
    android:id="@+id/mynav"
    />
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Drawer menu

```
  <item android:title="FeedBack"
      android:id="@+id/nav_item_feedback"
      android:icon="@drawable/feedback_icon"/>

<item android:title="Rate Us"
      android:id="@+id/nav_item_draft"
      android:icon="@drawable/rateus_icon"/>



<item android:title="Others">
    <menu>
        <item
            android:title="About"
            android:icon="@drawable/about_icon"/>
        <item android:title="Help"
            android:icon="@drawable/help"/>
    </menu>
</item>
```

MainActivity

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity{
DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;
NavigationView mNavigationView;
FragmentManager mFragmentManager;
FragmentTransaction mFragmentTransaction;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


    setTitle("DocVids");
    /**
     *Setup the DrawerLayout and NavigationView
     */

    mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawerLayout);
    mDrawerLayout.bringToFront();
    mNavigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.mynav) ;

    /**
     * Lets inflate the very first fragment
     * Here , we are inflating the TabFragment as the first Fragment
     */

    mFragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
    mFragmentTransaction = mFragmentManager.beginTransaction();
    mFragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.containerView,new TabFragment()).commit();
    /**
     * Setup click events on the Navigation View Items.
     */

    mNavigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(new NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem menuItem) {
            mDrawerLayout.closeDrawers();



            if (menuItem.getItemId() == R.id.nav_item_feedback) {
                FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = mFragmentManager.beginTransaction();
                fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.containerView,new FeedBack()).commit();

            }

            if (menuItem.getItemId() == R.id.nav_item_fav) {
                FragmentTransaction xfragmentTransaction = mFragmentManager.beginTransaction();
                xfragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.containerView,new TabFragment()).commit();
            }

            return false;
        }

    });


    /**
     * Setup Drawer Toggle of the Toolbar
     */

    android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar toolbar = (android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    ActionBarDrawerToggle mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this,mDrawerLayout, toolbar,R.string.app_name,
            R.string.app_name);

    mDrawerToggle.syncState();
    //mDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle);
    mDrawerLayout.addDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle);

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to put the drawer layout as the parent element, so your layout will become

```
    <android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/drawerLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#71b6ca"
    >
    <LinearLayout

        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="#71b6ca"
            android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
            app:title="DocVids"/>


        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/containerView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical">
        </FrameLayout>

        <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
            xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
            android:id="@+id/mynav"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="start"
            android:layout_marginTop="-24dp"
            app:menu="@menu/drawer"//Your drawer menu consisting of menu items
        />
    </LinearLayout>

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Check [this](http://www.android4devs.com/2015/06/navigation-view-material-design-support.html) example to get more info about usage of navigation menu

Comment: i got my mistake i just unintentionally removed the menue and some other things from XML now its back with the same linear layout as a parent view

Comment: however m considering your answer thanks for help :)

Answer (score 1):

In your **My xml**
Make  xml for navigation drawer like this:
**Make DrawerLayout as your parent Layout**

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
tools:openDrawer="start">

<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
    android:id="@+id/nav_view"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_home"
    app:menu="@menu/activity_home_drawer" />

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```